# Number theory for operator bound

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, real-analysis

Let $\gamma_i$ be such that for even $i$ $\gamma_i=1$ and for odd $i$ $\gamma_i$ shall have absolute value $1$ and the product of all of the odd ones is also on the complex unit circle but not 1 or -1.

I ask:

Is there a lower bound for the real part

$$\Re \sum_{i=0}^n \gamma_i x_i \overline{x_{i+1}}$$ such that $x_{n+1}:=x_0$ which is better than the trivial one $-\left\lVert x \right\rVert^2$ ?

Comment: To clarify: you want a bound that is expressed in terms of the $\gamma_i$?

Comment: yes, precisely..

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ be a point on the unit circle that is close to $1$, but $\alpha \neq  1$. Take the vector 
$$x = (1,-1,1,-1,\ldots)$$
of length $n$.Then
$$-\Vert x \Vert^2 = -n.$$
Set $\gamma_1 = \alpha$ and $\gamma_i = 1$ for all other odd $i$. Then the product of the $\gamma_i$ is $\pm \alpha$ which is not $\pm 1$ and we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma_i x_i\overline{x_{i+1}} = -\alpha -(n-1).$$
As we chose $\alpha$ to be close to $1$, the real part of this expression should be close to $-n$.

Formalizing this idea properly with $\epsilon \to 0$ you should be able to show that there is no better bound in general.

Comment: you are not allowed to choose gamma. Gamma is given and satisfies the above properties. Also, I think your proof is rather a "proof by example" which is of course not admissible. What is also funny is that you want to let epsilon go to zero without defining it anywhere in your text...

Comment: My "proof" is no proof at all, it is an example where the bound $-\Vert x \Vert^2$ is tight. So you can't find a better lower bound in general. If you now say that the $\gamma_i$ are fix, you might look for a bound that depends on them.

Comment: that is the point. the $\gamma_i$ are fixed and also you have another sum, don't you? we have $x_ix_{i+1}$